# Flex dispached event inside TitleWindow is not system wide?

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have a tree, which childs dispaching event, if i run the object outside TitleWindow - everything is working fine, but if i encapsulate it inside a TitleWindow as into the source below - the event is not anymore dispached system wide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:sparkTree="com.sparkTree.*"
               creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            private function init():void
            {
                PopUpManager.addPopUp( xWin, this );
                this.addEventListener( MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, function( e : MyEvent ):void{ Alert.show( ":P" ) } );
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TitleWindow id="xWin" >

        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%">
            <sparkTree:Tree labelField="label" 
                    dataProvider="{dataProviderXML}" 
                    width="300" height="500" 
                    textRollOverColor="yellow" 
                    textSelectedColor="0xFFFFFF"
                    itemRenderer="com.sparkTree.XItemRenderer">

                <sparkTree:layout>
                    <s:VerticalLayout gap="0" variableRowHeight="true"/>
                </sparkTree:layout>
            </sparkTree:Tree>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:TitleWindow>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your

```
this.addEventListener( MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, function( e : MyEvent ):void{ Alert.show( ":P" ) } );
```

to

```
xWin.addEventListener( MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, function( e : MyEvent ):void{ Alert.show( ":P" ) } );
```

Or maybe you're using event bubbling?

I don't know details about your code and see it very problematic but this code works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application creationComplete="init()" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function init():void
        {
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(xWin, this);
            systemManager.addEventListener(MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, function(e:MyEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(":P")
            });
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:TitleWindow id="xWin">
            <s:Button click="xWin.dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD))" horizontalCenter="0"
                verticalCenter="0" />
        </s:TitleWindow>
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Where `MyEvent` is:

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyEvent extends Event
{
    public static const REQUEST_FORWARD:String = "requestForward";

    public function MyEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type, true, false);
    }
}
}
```

But what about me personally I recommend to to change all your code :)

First of all I strongly recommend you to extract your window in a separate component (you should do it all the time and use inline components only for prototyping):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="requestForward", type="MyEvent")]
    </fx:Metadata>
    <s:Button click="dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD))" horizontalCenter="0"
        verticalCenter="0" />
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Second, don't use bubbling events without need especially outside components:

```
package
{
import flash.events.Event;

public class MyEvent extends Event
{
    public static const REQUEST_FORWARD:String = "requestForward";

    public function MyEvent(type:String)
    {
        super(type);
    }
}
}
```

Third, try not to use inner functions and create separate methods. It is more readable and it is easier to unsubscribe. So our final application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application creationComplete="init()" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

        protected function init():void
        {
            var win:MyWindow = MyWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, MyWindow));
            win.addEventListener(MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, win_requestForwardHandler);
        }

        private function win_requestForwardHandler(event:MyEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show(":P");
            var win:MyWindow = MyWindow(event.currentTarget);
            win.removeEventListener(MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, win_requestForwardHandler);
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Yep, i am using event bubling (sorry i miss it to add it)... the MyEvent is as follow :  public function MyEvent( type : String )
  {
   super( type, true, false );
  }

Comment: 1. What benefits of bubbling you have in your case? Don't use it. 2. If you can't live without it use `systemManager` to subscribe.

Comment: I dont know, i tought bubling will provide me more wide usage of the event. How to use systemManager to subscribe ?

Comment: You shouldn't abuse bubbling. It makes code less clear and litter your application. The best way is to subscribe events directly to the object which dispatches them (as in my answer).

Comment: To subscribe to `systemManager` just subscribe to it :) Every `UIComponent` has this property :)

Comment: systemManager.addEventListener( MyEvent.REQUEST_FORWARD, function( e : MyEvent ):void{ Alert.show( ":P" ) } ) ; ... still doesnt work :|

Comment: @Constantiner i am not actually getting it. Please explain.

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much Constantiner! Really appreciate your answer here.