# More than one TitleWindow instance?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, window

I just drop on a strange thing - i can not have 2 popup TitleWindows instances simultaneously.

- How can i have more than 1 TitleWindow instance which can be moved arround ?

Here is my code for a reference :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler( event:FlexEvent ) : void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PopUpManager.addPopUp( w1, this );
                PopUpManager.addPopUp( w2, this );
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TitleWindow id="w1" width="300" height="400">    
    </s:TitleWindow>

    <s:TitleWindow id="w2" width="300" height="400" x="300">
    </s:TitleWindow>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to my [previous answer to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6262327/680503). Create your window class. And add it the following way:

```
var win:MyWindow = MyWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, MyWindow));
```

as many times as you want.

Comment: my windowses is not instance of the same class. they hold different data, or you are referenceing that i can not and must not using MXML declared TitleWindows ?

Comment: I got the idea... but i tought there is a way not to separate each window into new component. :|

Comment: And what? What's the problem to extract window which "hold different data, or you are referenceing that i can not and must not using MXML declared TitleWindows" in a separate class (component). Just keep in mind MXML components are a kind of classes (with MXML syntax).

Comment: Extracting subcomponents is a good way to improve application design. And `TileWindow` represented in MXML is the best candidate for that.

Comment: Yeah ... Probably You are correct :) Thank you. goin this way then :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the [modal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/PopUpManager.html#addPopUp%28%29) property of the addPopUp to false.

```
        PopUpManager.addPopUp( w1, this, false );
        PopUpManager.addPopUp( w2, this, false );
```

Comment: nope. it still doesnt work @www.Flextras.com, probably something else is required... :|